# Android pIugin Unity: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized... Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context)

Tags: java, android, firebase, unity-game-engine, gradle

*EditBlock: I have Tested Firebase on a new empty project in android studio. The firebase initialize successfully. I am connected and am able to create users just fine. If I build a jar file to import into Unity and build the project there, the firebase initialization is unsuccessful. I can't seem to find why exactly either, but it feels like the connection between my app and firebase is no longer there, would greatly apreciate if anyone has an idea of what I am missing.*

I currently have an android activity that works, but only if built from Android Studio. It stops working when built from Unity ever since I added Firebase support. I have tried many different things from many different posts with issues similar to this one, but never managed to solve mine. I have different errors depending on the setup and am not sure which one is the closest to the solution. I am using PlayServiceResolver that is supposed to help with dependencies that are possibly duplicated. I know there is a lot of stuff in there, but I dont really know what else to try.

This is my current setup:

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
```

app.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "me.devhelp.unityplugin"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        }
    }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.2.0'
    provided files('libs/classes.jar')
}


task clearJar(type: Delete) {
    delete '/AndroidPlugin.jar'
}

task androidReleaseJar(type: Jar) {
    from "$buildDir/intermediates/classes/release/"
    exclude '**/BuildConfig.class'
    exclude '**/R.class'
    exclude '**/R$*.class'
    dependsOn 'assembleRelease'
}

task makeJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/libs/')
    into("$buildDir")
    include('app.jar')
    rename ('app.jar', 'AndroidPlugin.jar')
}

makeJar.dependsOn(clearJar, build)
clearJar.dependsOn('androidReleaseJar', build)

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

AndroidManifest.xml in Unity (the one in AndroidStudio is different since I use a normal Activity to test instead of a UnityPlayerActivity):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="me.devhelp.unityplugin">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

        <activity android:name="me.devhelp.unityplugin.UnityPluginActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <service
            android:name="me.devhelp.unityplugin.LocationService"
            android:process=":UnityPluginLocationService" />
        <provider
            android:name="me.devhelp.unityplugin.LocationContentProvider"
            android:authorities="me.devhelp.plugin.provider.store"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

If I install the apk from AndroidStudio, when I call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this) in the onCreate() of the activity, the init is successfull and I dont get a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException either when calling FirebaseAuth.getInstance(); However this is the Logcat error that I get after building from unity:

```
09-01 15:29:55.869 9875-9875/? I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
09-01 15:29:55.879 9875-9875/? I/LocationPlugin: DBHelper init
...
09-01 15:29:56.119 9875-9875/? I/LocationPlugin: UnityPluginActivity:onCreate
09-01 15:29:56.119 9875-9875/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
Process: me.devhelp.unityplugin, PID: 29432
java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION[main]
Unity version     : 5.6.1f1
Device model      : LGE LG-V497
Device fingerprint: lge/t8lte_rgs_ca/t8lte:5.0.2/LRX22G/152291201d423:user/release-keys

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{me.devhelp.unityplugin/me.devhelp.unityplugin.UnityPluginActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process me.devhelp.unityplugin.Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2345)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process me.devhelp.unityplugin.Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    ...
```

I used to have the dependency 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0' in the app.gradle and the AndroidStudio build works with or without it. But I get different errors (im guessing are related to duplication) if I add or not the dependency in the jar resolver script. If I dont add it, I get a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when calling FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this), and if I add it, the error is when the build is processing AAR plugins and it says that the system cannot find the file specified (Unity console):

```
IOException: Failed to Move File / Directory from 'Temp/StagingArea\android-libraries\firebase-core-11.2.0\classes.jar' to 'Temp/StagingArea\android-libraries\firebase-core-11.2.0\libs\classes.jar'.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.ProcessAAR.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, System.String downloadWebplayerUrl, System.String manualDownloadWebplayerUrl, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:186)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Another thing that might be related, I do get this error when the resolver registers the dependencies:

```
IOException: Directory C:\Users\TRIPLE ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jb5dcmui.673 is not empty
System.IO.Directory.Delete (System.String path) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Directory.cs:178)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport.DeleteExistingFileOrDirectory (System.String path, Boolean includeMetaFiles)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1.ShouldExplode (System.String aarPath)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1+<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey11.<>m__1D(GooglePlayServices.Result result)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1+<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey11+<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey12.<>m__26()
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver.PumpUpdateQueue ()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication.Internal_CallUpdateFunctions () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/editor/EditorApplicationBindings.gen.cs:249)
```

Comment: `FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful`. FirebaseInitProvider builds default FirebaseApp from resources. The only required resource is `@string/google_app_id` which is supposed to be generated for you by the `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` from `google-services.json`. Make sure you have your Firebase Project set up correctly (in Firebase Console, **including Android App with an App Id**) and that this file is updated.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not find a solution. I ended up using only the firebase that was in Unity and not the one in the service. What would normally have been sent from the service ended up in a small sql database and when the user would log into firebase from Unity we would then push whatever was stored in the sql db onto the firebase db and then clear the sql db.